# How to import deep learning models from MATLAB to PyTorch?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, pytorch

I’m trying to import a DNN trained model from MATLAB to PyTorch.

I’ve found solutions for the opposite case (from PyTorch to MATLAB), but no proposed solutions on how to import a trained model from MATLAB to PyTorch.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first [export your model to ONNX format](https://in.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/exportonnxnetwork.html), and then load it using [ONNX](https://pypi.org/project/onnx/); prerequisites are:

```
pip install onnx onnxruntime
```

Then,

```
onnx.load('model.onnx')
# Check that the IR is well formed
onnx.checker.check_model(model)
```

Until this point, you still don't have a PyTorch model. This can be done through various ways since it's [not natively supported](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/21683).

---

A [workaround](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/21683#issuecomment-641071485) (by loading *only* the model parameters)

```
import onnx
onnx_model = onnx.load('model.onnx')

graph = onnx_model.graph
initalizers = dict()
for init in graph.initializer:
    initalizers[init.name] = numpy_helper.to_array(init)

for name, p in model.named_parameters():
    p.data = (torch.from_numpy(initalizers[name])).data
```

---

Using [`onnx2pytorch`](https://pypi.org/project/onnx2pytorch/)

```
import onnx

from onnx2pytorch import ConvertModel

onnx_model = onnx.load('model.onnx')
pytorch_model = ConvertModel(onnx_model)
```

---

Note: Time Consuming

Using [`onnx2keras`](https://pypi.org/project/onnx2keras/), then [`MMdnn`](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn) to convert from Keras to PyTorch [(Examples)](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn#examples)

Comment: I'm gonna try it, Many thanks for the solution!

Comment: After converting the model using onnx2pytorch, how can I use the model to make a prediction, please?

Comment: Just the same way you would make a prediction with a PyTorch model. Not sure I understood your question? :)