# AttributeError: 'ConvertModel' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, pytorch, attributeerror, seek, onnx

I tried converting a MATLAB model to PyTorch using ONNX, like proposed here by Andrew Naguib:

[How to import deep learning models from MATLAB to PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66223768/how-to-import-deep-learning-models-from-matlab-to-pytorch)

I tried running the model using the following code:

```
import onnx
from onnx2pytorch import ConvertModel
import torch

onnx_model = onnx.load ('resnet50.onnx')

pytorch_model = ConvertModel(onnx_model)

model = torch.load(pytorch_model)
```

But I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'ConvertModel' object has no attribute 'seek'. You can
> only torch.load from a file that is seekable. Please pre-load the data
> into a buffer like io.BytesIO and try to load from it instead.

How can I fix it, please? Any ideas on how can I "pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `my_data.dat` is a file containing binary data, the following code loads it into an ioBytesIO buffer that is seekable:

```
import io

with open('my_data.dat', 'rb') as f:
    buf = io.BytesIO(f.read())
```

You can now write things like

```
    buf.seek(4)
```

and

```
    x = buf.read(1)
```

Of course, in your case, you're going through a `onnx.load` methdod, and I don't know what that does. But if does return a file object, on a binary file, then the above might help you.